# Excel SUM Function = 0 after RIGHT function

Tags: excel, sum, zero

I used this function

```
=RIGHT(D2,
   LEN(D2) - 
      MAX(
        IF(ISNUMBER(MID(D2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 1) *1)=FALSE,
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 
           0
        )
     )
 )
```

to remove only the right most numbers from a string mixed of letters, special characters, and numbers. I am trying to do some basic calculations with the values of the new column however the SUM function is only returning 0

I have tried with the data being General and Number, I have also tried using Text to column solution but they both don't seem to work

Comment: Your formula returns result as text. If you want to do calculation with returned numbers, wrap your formula with `VALUE()` or add +0 at the end or multiply everything by 1 to convert it to number

Comment: Quick Add on if some of the cells were blank as there are no number at the end of the string for the Right function to find. How would I turn those blanks into 0

Comment: there is no sum function in your formula. Please post the formula you actually use.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the image or string text looks like?

Answer (score 1):

This modified formula will extract the rightmost numbers from the string and convert them to numeric values in a single step.

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(D2,
   LEN(D2) - 
      MAX(
        IF(ISNUMBER(MID(D2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 1) *1)=FALSE,
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 
           0
        )
     )
 ))
```